# @vertx/eventbus-bridge-client.js integrate with OpenTelemetry

Tags: reactjs, websocket, quarkus, vert.x, open-telemetry

Hi I am trying to integrate react application with open telemetry. I use @vertx/eventbus-bridge-client.js in my clinet side to communicate with my quarkus backend. Any one know what is the library I want to use to trace the communication in my vertex event bus. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

On the Quarkus side you need to include this extension:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And follow this guide:
https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the answer. I also follow that tutorial. In my quarkus side it's working. But in the react app the event bus events cannot trace. Also in the front end, Http rest request can trace. Currently I am facing issue with tracking  @vertx/eventbus-bridge-client.js from react application